# Posting questions and answers to the site

Tags: discussion

New here but as most people I have a few problems that I have worked on. Where I couldnt just google a problem and find the answer (other people post same problems and nothing) and its not listed here on stackoverflow. Is there a place I can post the question and solution so that others can find the information if needed? Want to make sure I comply with rules and at the same time help others. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you can use the [`Ask Question`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button to the right-top of this site. Please also take the __[tour]__ and learn of the standards of the questions around here.

Comment: You can visit [meta], that site is to discuss the working and rules of Stack Overflow. Good luck and welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: See [What is this “answer your own question” jazz?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz)